# GitKraken: Disable SSL certificate verification for GitLab Self-Managed integration

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab, gitkraken

In GitKraken, I am trying to setup 'GitLab Self-Managed' integration for a server that has a certificate which I cannot verify. I want to ignore/bypass the certificate verification. Is it possible?